How do I store a negative TimeSpan in Entity Framework?
I store shifts to events with a TimeSpan as the offset from the start of the event and another TimeSpan as the duration of the shift. The setup shift starts before the event (so everyone see the event as 11:00am - 4:00pm as desired while the setup shift starts at 10:15am).
Entity Framework throws an exception saving a TimeSpan < 0 or >= 24:00:00. Is there a way to save a TimeSpan outside the 0 .. 24 hour range?

It sounds like you're using the (default) mapping of TimeSpan to T-SQL's time type - but the types are not equivalent. You can continue to use TimeSpan, but map it to a bigint column storing .Ticks - not time (which is strictly a 24-hour time-of-day value).

Does this answer your question? Storing TimeSpan with Entity Framework Codefirst - SqlDbType.Time overflow

TL;DR: use the built-in TimeSpanToTicksConverter, e.g. builder.Entity<Event>().Property(s => s.Shift).HasConversion(new TimeSpanToTicksConverter())

I always try to adhere to (at least) two principles when abstracting reality into data: 1. stay as close to the actual, physical, processes taking place 2. on the most basic (non-derived) level. Negative timespans are a model artefact. They don't exists. In fact, timespans in any form are derived artefacts. If you store time spans, the distance between reality and model is larger than necessary and the need for contrivances (like negative timespans) is a tell-tale of that phenomenon. Just store start and end times (ideal and actual). Time spans can always be calculated later.

You can set it as follows to then have both negative values and positive values > 24 hours.
public class ShiftConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Shift>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Shift> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(s => s.Duration).HasConversion(new TimeSpanToTicksConverter());
    }
}

